# Python - Selenium get stuck

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to make a script in python that's going to download all the files from a website that I'm asking for. I'm new to Selenium so I'm not sure if is something wrong or not but.

```
for link in thredds_links:
    current_ind += 1
    print("LINK: ", current_ind, len(thredds_links))
    driver.get(link)
    data = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(".nc")
    data_link = [l.get_attribute('href') for l in data]

    current_ind_2 = 0
    for d in data_link:
        current_ind_2 += 1
        print("LINK_2: ", current_ind_2, len(data_link))

        # link_d = d.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(d)

        download_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("HTTPServer").get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(download_link)

        driver.find_element_by_class_name("custom-combobox-input").send_keys("USER_NAME")
        driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("SOME_PASSWORD")
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()
```

In the first for-loop, I have 10 links with each link contain another 10-14 files to be downloaded into the second for-loop. But for some reason, the Firefox is going to get stuck at the second link from the second for-loop and it's going to crash of timeout after a while even if I have all the link from that list correctly.

Comment: As a suggestion try to add "time.sleep(2)" after driver.get lines and see if there is any difference or not. I faced that problem long back and with sleep every thing worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar script that downloads multiple pdfs from a link and moves on to the next and I had the same problem....I fixed it at my end by looping through a range(len(iterable)) so in your case i think it would be

```
for d in range(len(data_link)):
```

Give it a try....Kuda